# Função agregada com MIN(), GROUP BY e Subquery

Tags: mysql

Estou enfrentando problemas para montar um query de uma tabela de endereços com latitude e longitude.

Tenho uma função que faz um cálculo de distância, chamei ela de: 
`distance_latlng_km(originLat, originLng, destLat, destLng)`.

Na tabela tenhos alguns campos importantes que gostaria de retornar. São eles:
**id, user_id, lat, lng**

Minha query está assim:

```
SELECT id, user_id, lat, lng, distance_latlng_km(x, y, lat, lng) as distance FROM addresses;
```

Isto me retorna correto, listando pra mim o **ID do endereço**, **usuário dono do endereço**, **latitude**, **longitude** e a **distancia em km** resultante do calculo da latitude e longitude.

O grande problema é que um **usuário** pode ter **mais de um endereço**, então a minha necessidade é trazer **um** endereço por usuário, se um usuário tiver mais de um endereço, gostaria de pegar o de **menor distância**.

#### Minha query atual:

```
SELECT b.id, b.user_id, b.lat, b.lng, distance_latlng_km(x, y, b.lat, b.lng) as distance 
FROM (SELECT user_id, min(distance_latlng_km(x, y, lat, lng)) FROM address GROUP BY user_id) a 
INNER JOIN address b ON b.user_id = a.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
    A.ID, A.USER_ID, A.LAT, A.LNG, DISTANCE_LATLNG_KM(X, Y, A.LAT, A.LNG) AS DISTANCE 
FROM 
    ADDRESS A
WHERE
    DISTANCE_LATLNG_KM(X, Y, A.LAT, A.LNG) = (SELECT MIN(DISTANCE_LATLNG_KM(X, Y, B.LAT, B.LNG)) FROM ADDRESS B WHERE B.USER_ID = A.USER_ID)
```

Isso assumindo que o mesmo usuário não possui registros de ID diferente com a mesma latitude e longitude. E que seja esperado como resultado registros de ID's diferentes com latitude e longitude diferentes, mas com a mesma distância.

Comment: Isso funcionou sim, agora o meu problema é outro, no qual preciso juntar isso e usar em conjuto com mais quatro tabelas, podes me ajudar? Se houvesse um canal onde pudêssemos conversar, seria bom.

Comment: Marca a resposta como correta e edita a pergunta indicando os novos dados e edito a resposta se conseguir ajudar.

Comment: @ItaloIzaac se a pergunta foi respondida, o ideal é você marcar a resposta como correta e criar outra pergunta com o novo problema.